# How to find out (debug) why ( /etc/rc.d/rc.local ) not executing a command that works ok via terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

There is a command inside my

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

i am not sure why it is not being executed.

i think i either need to add #!bash or something on top of the script
or perhaps i need to add `gnome-terminal` infront of the line being executed.

but is there a way to find out what the error is?

this is the command by the way:

```
/usr/X11R6/bin/xautolock -time 1 -locker "/root/shut_off"
```

works fine via terminal.

Comment: Not `#!bash`. Look up *shebang*. Summarised, if you have an executable script which needs bash to interpreted it then the first line should be either point to the interpreter (e.g. `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`) or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. The latter is more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a command that relies on a running X server to a file that is run before the X server has been initialized and will, in any case, not be run by the user who started the server but by root.

What is it you want to do? If you just want that command to be run every time you log in for example, add it to your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if that file exists and you are using bash).